# Add text to live stream video in Android

Tags: android, live-streaming

I want to add text to a live stream video similar to Periscope app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.periscope.android&hl=en

I need the text to be overplayed on the screen. I would be very thankful if someone help me in that. You don't need to write code just the procedure and if there is any online tutorial will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of text is it? The messages being sent to the broadcaster?

Comment: @WannaBeGeekSimple text/normal text. The user enters text he want and the text should be overplayed to the live stream video. Like the Periscope app.

Comment: Won't  a simple TextView helpful over here?

Comment: I mean a TextView overlaying your Video View in a XML file .

Comment: @WannaBeGeek i want the text to be broadcast. So that anyone who is watching the live video will see the text added by the user. Sounds make sense?

Comment: 1)register an event with text submit event 2)and broadcast it with data to receiver(I am assuming you know how to work with broadcast receiver) 3)inside onReceive() in broadcast do what you want to do

Comment: @kishor_Joshi  how to make Periscope load the text of the user when watching that live stream on Periscope ?